# SQL: ROW_NUMBER with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following code to partition and then assign a rank to a column based on the data in another column, however, if all of the values for that particular partition are 0 or there are 2 the same it still increments the row number, as this is rankings I need any values that are the same to be ranked the same.

```
with toupdate as (
select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RaceID ORDER BY TotalToday DESC) TDR
from Ratings t
 )
update toupdate
set TotalTodayRank = TDR;
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: just use rank function.

Comment: Use [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176102.aspx) or [DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173825.aspx) depending on your requirements. Dense_rank will ensure a continuous sequence (i.e. 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), whereas rank will keep inline with row_number (i.e. 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6).